# JTextPane#getText() does not return text of Components

Tags: java, swing

I need to implement a TextPane to which contents will be added dynamically on the go. It can have text and links.

The links can be displayed by adding JLabel to the textPane. But the issue is, all the text the textPane has, needs to be stored to a file. `textPane.getText()` returns text but it does not append any text of the components added to the textPane.
For example if textPane has a String("Hello") and a JLabel("label"). `textPane.getText()` returns only "hello". How do I retrieve "label" ??

Comment: Although `JTextPane` is a `Container`, it is not meant to add `Component`s to imo. If you want to display links, why not just opt for `JTextComponent` which has support for HTML and create a link in HTML.

Comment: Hmm thanks. But I cant as I am addign a functionality lying on TextPane. Backward Compatibility

Comment: Another issue with html is that, the content is added dynamically on teh go. I will have to keep modifying the html page for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `getText()` represents content of the Document. For your goal you should iterate through the Character `Elements` and for each of them check whether attributes has `Component`. Then cast to e.g. `JLabel` and get text etc.

Also check how the component is added to the `JTextPane`. You can add your component into attributes and insert an appropriate string with the attributes.

```
SimpleAttributeSet attrs=new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setComponent(...yourLabel);
documnet.insertString(offset, yourLabel.getText(), attrs);
```

Then your `Document` has the text of the `JLabel`.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly how I added labels. Another issue is that; i want to reload the textPane from a file (including JLabels). I have done it by surrounding the text to be added in a JLabel by usign quotes around it. Can their be a better way? Serialization??

Comment: I would add an artificial attribute e.g. "MyMarker" with some value. When it's necessary to reload scn all character Elements via getCharacterElement() method of the Document. Then check the marker value and updte the text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to write a method that recursively traverses through a component structure, retrieving the text of each node (if any) and appending it. In pseudo code, it'd look something like this:

```
public void collectText(Container root) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    collectText(root, builder);

    return builder.toString();
}

private void collectText(Container root, StringBuilder builder) {
    builder.append(root.getText());

    for (Component c : root.getComponents()) {
        // Check whether this component has other components
        if (c instanceof Container) {
            collectText((Container) c, builder);
        } else {
            // Check whether this Component has text content, and append it to the builder
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, it starts with one component - that would be your `TextPane`, and then traverses any elements below. Optionally, you could check whether the child components actually *have* text before appending its text contents to the buffer. After having traversed the elements, it returns the contents of the buffer.

**Edit**

Although [`Container#getComponents()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) JavaDoc doesn't say anything about it, I *assume* it'll always return it's child components in the same order (since it uses `List#toArray()` internally).

Comment: Here the TextPane has components. And the order of the text needs to be maintained. How will the order be maintained above